# How to Navigate from a UIView class to a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, navigation

I have a UIView which I am using as a seperate module and can include it anywhere I want to. Now I want to navigate to a UIViewController on click of the button inside the UIView.
Hope this is pretty clear.

Comment: Hope this is pretty clear. - No, it is not :)

Comment: you can't do that directly , you need to implement delegate form your UIView Class and pass it to it's parent view controller from there you can do navigation  is it pretty clear ? :)

Comment: You should implement delegate in your view

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You shouldn't. You need to read up on the MVC design pattern. A `UIView` is a view object. You are trying to add controller behavior to a view object.

You should take a look at parent/child view controllers, container views, and embed segues. You could easily create a view controller that manages a "tile" inside another view controller, and sends messages to it's parent when the user taps buttons. This is a very common way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to supply the ViewController to the view as a delegate, conforming to a protocol you create for it.

For instance, if you UIView is used to pick an image, then the delegate should have a method akin to:

- (void)view:(UIView*)view choseImage:(UIImage*)image;